# Custom property in Google App Engine. Value sent to Make_value_from_datastore is not of the type saved

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use a JsonProperty with the google app engine datastore.

Using this code ( The indentation is right on my computer )

```
class JsonProperty(SerialProperty):
"""Stores a dictionary automatically encoding to JSON on set and decoding                                                                                                                 
on get.                                                                                                                                                                                   
"""
data_type = dict

def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    self._require_parameter(kwds, 'indexed', False)
    kwds['indexed'] = True
    super(JsonProperty, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    """Encodes the value to JSON."""
    value = super(JsonProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(
        model_instance)
    if value is not None:
        return db.Text(json.dumps(value))
    else:
        return db.Text("{}")

def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    value=super(JsonProperty, self).make_value_from_datastore(value)
    logging.error(value)
    """Decodes the value from JSON."""
    if value is not None:
        return json.loads(value)

def validate(self, value):
    if value is not None and not isinstance(value, (dict, list, tuple)):
        raise db.BadValueError('Property %s must be a dict, list or '
                                       'tuple.' % self.name)
```

But when I get the "value" in make_value_from_datastore, instead of being type db.Text, it is of type JsonProperty.

I can see the string in the datastore, and it is saving correctly.

When it is loaded, it chokes on json.loads(value), because json wants a "string or buffer"

I don't understand, and can't find any difference between my code and several examples on the internet, all of which indicate that the value of "value" should be the raw type that was saved to the datastore.

Comment: Can you switch to NDB? Because it has a working JsonProperty. (Shameless plug... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the value you get back is a db.Text value, rather than a string.  Does this work?

```
def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    value=super(JsonProperty, self).make_value_from_datastore(value)
    logging.error(value)
    """Decodes the value from JSON."""
    if value is not None:
        return json.loads(str(value))
```